# Зачем устанавливать пакет apache maven и прописывать m2_home если maven уже встроен в Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, apache, intellij-idea, maven

Уважаемые коллеги, подскажите пожалуйста можем ли мы собирать проект если у нас поставлена **Intellij IDEA**, но мы специально не скачивали maven с официального сайта и соответственно не прописывали **m2_home**?
Какие возможности становятся недоступными, если мы не установили **apache** **maven** и не прописали **m2_home** в переменных средах?

Comment: Если вы хотите собирать проект из командной строки, а не кнопкой в IDEA, вам потребуется m2_home (можно переиспользовать идеевский) и мавен в PATH.

Comment: @Nofate может вы дадите здесь более развернутый ответ с опциональным пояснением, какие возможности даёт сборка из командной строки, которых нет intellij idea? А я с удовольствием приму ваш ответ.